# Django: Where to put global models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a fairly large website in Django, and it's my first time doing anything of this scale with the framework. (I have, however, used it in the past, so I know my way around and am not a total newbie.)  I have a number of model classes which will be used throughout the application, so my question is where would be the best place to put them?

I could also use some tips as to how to structure my project. I don't want to have some crazy hierarchy, and I'd like to use `./manage.py startapp` as sparingly as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to make a "main" application and then import the models from that application into your other peripheral apps when you need the main models.

```
manage.py startapp main
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the differences between apps and projects, but it still just seems weird to me to have to create a app which holds all subapps... within a project. One would think that a Django projest itself would be an app. In any case, thanks, I'll probably just end up following your advice :-)

Comment: I too have had this issue before but later figured that the problem I saw was not actually a problem -- not all apps have to be stand-alone and replaceable parts in a system, they are allowed to depend on a "mother app", nothing is stopping you. :)